# extracting data from crystal reports file into sql

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

i need to extract data from thousands of `crystal report 2008 files` into SQL database. 
data i need is

- name of the crystal file
- stored procedure crystal is using
- Server
- Database SP used
- Fields displayed
- Summary info such as Author
- Keywords,Comments,Subject
- Parameters

  and so on.

Does anyone have any idea how i can accomplish this and maybe a code example.i was told this can be done using VB but no idea how to do it. any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This shows you how to set connection info. You can use the same code essentially to get connection info:

```
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim cryRpt As New ReportDocument
        Dim crtableLogoninfos As New TableLogOnInfos
        Dim crtableLogoninfo As New TableLogOnInfo
        Dim crConnectionInfo As New ConnectionInfo
        Dim CrTables As Tables
        Dim CrTable As Table

        cryRpt.Load("PUT CRYSTAL REPORT PATH HERE\CrystalReport1.rpt")

        With crConnectionInfo
            .ServerName = "YOUR SERVER NAME"
            .DatabaseName = "YOUR DATABASE NAME"
            .UserID = "YOUR DATABASE USERNAME"
            .Password = "YOUR DATABASE PASSWORD"
        End With

        CrTables = cryRpt.Database.Tables
        For Each CrTable In CrTables
            crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo
            crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo
            CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo)
        Next

        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt
        CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
    End Sub
End Class
```

From: http://vb.net-informations.com/crystal-report/vb.net_crystal_report_load_dynamically.htm

You should be able to suss the others bits out by exploring the ReportDocument.ReportObjects